# Trigger Jenkins job on change of directory content

Tags: deployment, jenkins

Below is the problem,

There is a directory,Lets called is user/mydir
Is it possible to trigger  a jenkins job on any change to this direcory (eg:copy a file , delete a file ,create a file in the directory).

Any feedback will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [FSTrigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FSTrigger+Plugin) to do that.

Comment: Hi , 
Than you very much for the reply.
I configured the  **[FSTrigger] - Monitor folder** to the path _/home/jenkinspollfolder_  
when i create a file in the folder , the job is still failing to build/trigger

Comment: You need to use the "[FSTrigger] - Monitor files" option and use a pattern like "/home/jenkinspollfolder/*.txt".

Comment: I have specified the path _/home/jenkinspollfolder/*.txt_ and set **Schedule** to _H/51 * * * *_ and I get message below that it had run on scheduled time .
But the FSTrigger Files Log shows that, [FSTrigger] - Monitor files
Polling has not run yet.
The job is still failing to build

Comment: Try a shorter interval like H/2 * * * * to test the polling. I think the text below the schedule input field shows just example values to test the input.

Comment: Yes I tried that too..but still the job is failing ...the text below keeps changing the last poll time according to the interval I provide ...

Comment: Anything in the Jenkins log? Which versions of Jenkins and the FSTrigger plugin are you using?

Comment: Hi,It finnaly worked..... I used **[FSTrigger] - Monitor folder** and i had to create files not folders in the specified directory..
Thank you very much for the help..:)

Comment: I've tried to use this, but it appears that FSTrigger works on a file or folder contents, but cannot do a folder tree.  Still looking for that solution.